# How can I embed a dynamically created combobox to a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to create a combobox embedded to a cell.

The code finds the first available row, in this case would be 12 and offsets to column:

```vb
Dim ctop#, cleft#, cht#, cwdth#
Dim ComboBox As OLEObject
                
ctop = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O35").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Top
cleft = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O35").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Left
cht = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O35").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Height
cwdth = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O35").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Width
                    
With ws_new
Set ComboBox = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Left:=cleft, Top:=ctop, Width:=cwdth, Height:=cht)
End With
                    
ComboBox.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
```

This code creates a combobox somewhere between Q12 and R12, and it is not embedded to the cell. Combobox resizes with the column and row, but it is not attached to a single cell.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of what the code does for me]

Comment: I ran your code, it works correctly. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: See the original post for screenshot. This code is a part of a loop, so the end result is list of boxes.

Comment: The code worked perfectly for me, placing a box in column T exactly as required. **Then I noticed your screenshot** - you're in *Page Layout* view. When I switched to *Page Layout* view, the code then behaves differently.